# How to check strlen of multiple input fields with short code

Tags: php

Multiple input fields like

```
<input type="text" name="row1[]" id="date1">
<input type="text" name="row1[]" id="amount1">
<input type="text" name="row1[]" id="name1">
<input type="text" name="row1[]" id="document1">
```

Want to check if number of characters in certain fields (**not all fields**) is at least 1 (in the example do not want to check number of characters in id="document1". Now using this code

```
if ( (strlen($_POST['row1'][0]) >= 1) or (strlen($_POST['row1'][1]) >= 1) or (strlen($_POST['row1'][2]) >= 1)) ) {
}
```

Is it possible to shorten code to something like (this is not working code)?

```
if ( (strlen($_POST['row1']??want_to_check??) >= 1) ) {
}
```

And input something like (also not working and not real)

```
<input type="text" name="row1[]??want_to_check??" id="date1">
<input type="text" name="row1[]??want_to_check??" id="amount1">
<input type="text" name="row1[]??want_to_check??" id="name1">
<input type="text" name="row1[]??do_not_want_to_check??" id="document1">
```

Check number of characters only in certain fields (not all fields)

Comment: why do you want to edit more that one record at a time? Why don't you make a form to edit single record only?

Comment: Final aim is not to edit. Final aim is to insert in mysql. If number of characters in certain (not all) input fields is at least 1, then insert. I try to find short code how to check number of characters in input fields.... Seems solution is to exclude certain fields from loop (if it is possible).

Answer (score 1):

a tricky shorthand

```
if (count(array_filter($_POST['row1'],'trim')) != count($_POST['row1'])) {
    //not all fields are set
}
```

but in general, if you see a repetition - you can be sure that a **loop** can be used. Look:

```
if ( (
    strlen($_POST['row1'][0]) >= 1) 
or (strlen($_POST['row1'][1]) >= 1) 
or (strlen($_POST['row1'][2]) >= 1)) )
```

three repeated operators with only counter changing. I am sure you can write a loop for this. Can't you?

Update

1. Make sensible field names

   ```
   <input type="text" name="row1[date]" id="date1">
   <input type="text" name="row1[amount]" id="amount1">
   <input type="text" name="row1[name]" id="name1">
   <input type="text" name="row1[document]" id="document1">
   ```
2. Create an array with required field names

   ```
   $req = array('date1','amount1','name1');
   ```
3. Check your input against this array in a loop

Comment: .... it appears at the moment I have not enough knowledge about this. Will learn. At the moment can not understand first code. And loop also can not write. Thanks for direction (where to go).

Comment: count(array_filter($_POST['row1'],'trim')) counts number of non empty input fields... any field that is not empty. As I understand loop also goes through all input fields. My aim is to check only certain fields, like name="row1[]" id="want_to_check1" name="row1[]" id="do_not_want_to_check1" name="row1[]" id="want_to_check2"

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work

```
function checkLength($inputs) {
    foreach($inputs as $input) {
        if(strlen($input) < 1) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

if(checkLength(array($_POST['input1'], $_POST['input2'], $_POST['input3']))) {

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can loop through fields using `foreach`

```
$field_set = false;
if(!empty($_POST['row1'])){
    foreach($_POST['row1'] as $key => $row){
        //Your code here
        if(trim($_POST['row1']))
            $field_set = true;
    }
}
```

This will work if you have dynamic number of fields.